# Two activities, but two icons

Tags: android

I'm developing an android activity using two activities:

- one for the splash screen and the loading from several URL
- one for the main process

The thing is for a reason I can't explain, it generates two icons instead of one then. I don't know what is wrong but I just would like to have one. Here is my manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com. ... .myapplication" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.OpenGL_ES_V2" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />



    <application
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/greenpolcircle"
        android:launchMode="standard"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/theme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="..." />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.baidu.lbsapi.API_KEY" android:value="..." />
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />


        <!-- Splash screen -->
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="appli"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="appli"
            android:theme="@style/theme">
            <!--android:label="@string/app_name" >-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You have 2 activities with Launcher intent so Android create 2 icons. Just remove 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

from the MainActivity intent-filter

It means "This activity is an entry point of this application", so if you define two **Launcher**, your application will have two entry points with two application icons.

Comment: You're damn right... my android's beginner-ness strikes again... Thanks a lot.